# Ignoring optional argument in bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies, citing, optional-arguments

I have a long list of references that are of the form, for example:

```
\bibitem[optionalarg]{label} Text of the reference
```

When I compile the source, this makes the cited reference to appears as `[optionalarg]` in the text, instead that as numbers `[X]`.

Is there a way to tell BibTeX to ignore that optional argument?

Here's a minimal example showing my problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title[Short title]{Long title}

\maketitle

This is a minimal example of what I wouldn't like (see \cite{ref1}). And of what I would like (see \cite{ref2}).

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
    \bibitem[Author1 and Author2(2013)]{ref1}
    Author1, I., \& Author2, I. (2013). Some title. \emph{Some journal}, X: xx--yy.
    \bibitem{ref2}
    Author3, I., \& Author4, I. (2013). Some other title. \emph{Some other journal}, X: xx--yy.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this is what `optionalarg` is supposed to do. Why did you use it in the first place? And why are you generating your biblography by hand? An automaticc solution would be easier to handle.

Comment: In a previous version of the paper optionalarg was used to have exactly that effect, that is to have the references to appear as, for example "see [John and Smith (2015)]". But now I have changed paper style and I would like to have it to appear as "see [1]". Of course, I could simply delete that optionarg from each reference, but it is quite an annoying task. I don't understand your remark about generating my bibliography by hand, I am using BibTex.

Comment: It is rather unclear (to me) how you are constructing your `.tex` file with respect to the bibliography. If you would provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) your question would be much clearer and an answer would be more likely to appear.

Comment: And of course using external tools to convert `\bibitem[optionalarg]{label}` to `\bibitem{label}` would not be difficult if you are writing those 'by hand'.

Comment: Ok I add above a minimal example. I will however consider your suggestion for an external tool.

Comment: If you're hard-coding your bibliography the way you seem to be doing, this doesn't have anything to do with BibTeX.

Comment: You're right, I have been quite inaccurate in referring to BibTex. What I mean is if it is possible to do what I want inside the compilation process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\bibitem[<opt>]{<key>}` to ignore `[<opt>]` by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem% Copy \bibitem into \oldbibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\oldbibitem{#2}}% Redefine \bibitem to only use mandatory arg
```

The above code stores `\bibitem` before redefining it to only pass the mandatory argument and ignore any optional arguments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\oldbibitem{#2}}

\begin{document}

\title[Short title]{Long title}

\maketitle

This is a minimal example of what I wouldn't like (see \cite{ref1}). And of what I would like (see \cite{ref2}).

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
  \bibitem[Author1 and Author2(2013)]{ref1}
    Author1, I., \& Author2, I. (2013). Some title. \emph{Some journal}, X: xx--yy.
  \bibitem{ref2}
    Author3, I., \& Author4, I. (2013). Some other title. \emph{Some other journal}, X: xx--yy.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```