# Change bibitem labels or avoid them altogether

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, labels

I have the example code `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
This is a citation~\cite{testArticle}.
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{lit}
\end{document}
```

And a file for the bibliography `lit.bib`:

```
@article{testArticle,
  title={This is a test article},
  author={Lastname, Firstname},
  journal={This is a test journal},
  year={2021},
  pages={1--2},
  volume={1},
  number={1}
}
```

If I compile this with pdflatex and bibtex I get the `test.bbl` file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[Lastname, 2021]{testArticle}
Lastname, F. (2021).
\newblock This is a test article.
\newblock {\em This is a test journal}, 1(1):1--2.

\end{thebibliography}
```

As you can see the label `[Lastname, 2021]` is added to the bbl file.

Questions:

- Can I tell the compiler to generate a different, customized label for some bibitems?
- Can I suppress the generation of these labels altogether (for all bibitems)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These optional arguments for `\bibitem` control how the citation is displayed in text and is therefore dependent on your bibliography style. This is just how citations look in the `apalike` style. To fix that permanently you would have to choose a different style or define your own that suits your needs (which is not the most pleasant thing to do).

As for your questions:

- You either define your own style or abandon bibtex and start using just the plain `thebibliography` environment with `\bibitem` entries, where you can define these labels however you please. Maybe also look into biblatex with the biber backend, there might be room for such customization there, but I do not know.
- As above, but there is actually a workaround here. Since you are essentially importing the `test.bbl` file which is full of `\bibitem` entries, you can simply redefine `\bibitem` to ignore its optional argument and display citations as plain numbers, as described in the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299968/ignoring-optional-argument-in-bibliography-entries). Note that the labels will still be generated, but will be ignored.

TL;DR for the 2nd question - insert this into your preamble:

```
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}[2][]{\oldbibitem{#2}}
```

Hope this helps somewhat.